# Show chooser from PreferenceActivity xml Android

Tags: android, android-intent, preferenceactivity

UPDATE

I am getting this error :

```
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
```

Here is the updated code :

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Add a button to the header list.
        if (hasHeaders()) {
            TextView txt = new TextView(this);
            txt.setText("Falcon pro version 1.2 @falcon");
            txt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            setListFooter(txt);
        }

        Preference sharingPref = findPreference("sharing");

        sharingPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Share application");
            String shareMessage = "My text";
            shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMessage);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"));
            return true;
        });

    }

    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preferences, target);
    }

}
```

================================================================================

Is there any way to show an android chooser when the user click on android preference ?

Or is it possible to make a call to this code from preference xml ?

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Share application");
String shareMessage = "My text";
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMessage);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"));
```

Answer (score 3):

To access a menu item in a preferenceActivity you can request the preference like this:

```
Preference sharingPref = findPreference("sharing");
```

"sharing" is the `key` of the preference.

With this you can just add a `setOnPreferenceClickListener` like this:

```
sharingPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
   public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
       Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
       shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
       shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Share application");
       String shareMessage = "My text";
       shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMessage);
       startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"));
       return true;
   }
});
```

**UPDATE**

I sorry, I missed a line in my original code:

```
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
```

I've updated it now.

Comment: Thanks, i have edited my post, i have a problem with your code. Please have a look of my updated post.

Comment: Updated, we all have bugs sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the Android guidelines for designing preferences:

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/settings.html

and refer to the Api Guide for a quick but complete overview of the Preference class:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html

Maybe ListPreference is what you're looking for.